# Extend partition in KVM

Tags: linux-kvm

I want to extend my qcow2 image file. We have installed a windows machine on it. Below are the steps we performed.

```
virt-filesystems --long -h --all -a windows-7-64.qcow2

truncate -s windows-7-64.qcow2 windows-7-64.qcow2.new

truncate -s +5G windows-7-64.qcow2.new

virt-resize --expand /dev/sda2 windows-7-64.qcow2 windows-7-64.qcow2.new
```

And finally, I renamed my `windows-7-64.qcow2.new` qcow2 image to an existing image, but it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "It is not working" in what way?  The rename? Booting Windows? Starting the VM?

Comment: qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata  /home/tempimages/newimage.qcow2 25G
virt-resize --expand /dev/sda2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/oldimage.qcow2 /home/tempimages/newimage.qcow2
mv /home/tempimages/newimage.qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/oldimage.qcow2

Comment: On above Example I have extended the Virtual Hard Disk 20G to 25G with  NFS resize method so I have created a new qcow2 image with qemu-img command and run the virt-resize command to extend the drive & moved back to orig location.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate will not work while expanding the drive in KVM, we need to use the below command

qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata windows-7-64.qcow2.new 25G

## run above command to create qcow2 image with expanded size, in my case 25 GB

virt-filesystems --long -h --all -a windows-7-64.qcow2

## run above command to check the file system on your qcow2 image.

virt-resize --expand /dev/sda2 windows-7-64.qcow2 windows-7-64.qcow2.new

## run virt-resize --expand to expand the drive.

## Note it is also recommend by openstack as well : http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/openstack-image/content/ch_modifying_images.html

## Note : after extending the drive we need to run diskpart utility manually on windows VM.

Comment: But I do not want to run diskpart utility manually on Windows VM. This is most of the cloud company use to do it like https://www.digitalocean.com/ and http://www.stormondemand.com/